# Using sed to match regex

Tags: regex, sed

I don't know much about sed, nor regex. I want to replace every line that contains only tabs by the string '0'. There are also lines in my file that contain only '\n'.

Basically I want to use the regular expression ^\h+$ and replace the matches with 0.

I tried:

```
sed -i 's/^\h+$/0/' file.txt
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: `\h` is supported only in PCRE, Boost and Java regex to match any horizontal whitespace. If you need to specifically match and replace one or more tabs, use `sed -i 's/^\t\t*$/0/' file.txt`. Or use the `[:blank:]` POSIX character class as is suggested below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
sed -i.bak -E 's/^[[:blank:]]+$/0/' file
```

POSIX character class `[[:blank:]]` matches a space or tab which is same as `\h` in PCRE.

`-i.bak` is to keep original file in `file.bak`, in case you want to restore.

Comment: Should this work as well case the lines that contain tabs have more than one tab?

Comment: Yes `[[:blank:]]+` will match one or more space or tab characters.

Comment: Is there a mistake in the command? I'm getting "sed: can't read s/^[[:blank:]]+$/0/: No such file or directory"

Comment: Use: `sed -i.bak -E 's/^[[:blank:]]+$/0/' file`

Comment: @FilipeAleixo, mind your quotes! Quotes are very important in shell. Enclose the sed script in single quotes, as anubhava demonstrated in his answer.

Comment: Strangely enough, this does nothing in my file. I tried on a small sample of the file though, and it worked. Here's the complete file https://pastebin.com/raw/0DyewpAd what am I missing here?

Comment: It is because your input file contains DOS line endings. You can use: `sed -i.bak -E 's/\r$//; s/^[[:blank:]]+$/0/' file`

Answer (score 1):

In `sed` the tabulator is called `\t`. One-or-more need a backslash `\+`:

```
 sed -i -e 's/^\t\+$/0/' file.txt
```

Comment: This use of the `-i` option fails in non-GNU versions of sed (macOS, FreeBSD, etc). I recommend you either specify a backup extension in a way that works portably, or just don't suggest non-portable options.